# %u problem in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding

Characters such as "š" when sent in a POST parameter and echo'd come out as `%u015F` - now I know this a hexidecimal value of the html unicode character - ie `&#351`; but how do I go about converting these?

I have characters sets set to UTF-8 and I've experimented with ISO character sets with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear I want the output to be & # 3 5 3; - the question above was converted to the ş character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve never seen that a client would send `%u015F` instead of the UTF-8 encoded `%C5%9F`. But try this:

```
preg_replace('/%u([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/e', 'mb_convert_encoding("\x$1\x$2", \'UTF-8\', \'UTF-16BE\')', $str)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlentities(urldecode($string))
```